# Where does Homebrew install wine?

Tags: homebrew, wine

I'd ask this on Homebrew's own community, but it doesn't seem like there is one.

I'm trying to install wine with Homebrew, but it doesn't look like anything's in the right place.

That is, "which wine" returns nothing, and "brew link wine" returns "Error: No such keg: /usr/local/Cellar/wine".

So where did brew install wine to? And where should I put the folder once I find it?

I can post my brew doctor output if you want, but I don't think anything in there was related.

Comment: Have you done a search? `brew search wine`? Also, what is wine?

Answer (score 3):

Brew *should* install the wine in `/usr/local/Cellar`. Have you ran `brew update && brew upgrade wine`? I always use the GUI (Wineskin) which can be installed via `brew cask`. However, I also have the CLI and it works fine.

Comment: Running "brew update && brew upgrade wine" returns "Error: No such file or directory - /usr/local/Cellar/wine". Which, at this point, is to be expected.

I normally use Wineskin as well, but I've come across a tutorial that requires the reader to edit user.reg and change the configuration.

Comment: @HalMeticulous have you installed wine via `brew install wine`?

Comment: Yes, I did. Sorry for not clarifying

Comment: @HalMeticulous and have you tried uninstalling and reinstalling it?

Comment: How? brew uninstall wine returns another no such keg error. Although yes, I have tried running the install script multiple times to no avail.